# Animate change div height from top and bottom at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change div height using animation from both sides (top,bottom) at the same time. How to do it right?

Here is my example, I can't integrate the both animations in same time.
Or maybe there is some css solution?

```js
$('div').click(function(){
     $init = $(this).height(); 
     $slice = 60;
    $(this).animate({
 
 marginTop:$init-$slice +'px',
 height:$slice+'px'
 }, 1000);
$(this).animate({
 
 height:'20px'
 }, 1000);
})
```

```css
.square {
height:100px;
width: 100px;
background:black;
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square">

  1<br>
  2<br>
  3<br>
  4<br>
  5<br>
  6<br>
  7<br>
  8<br>
  9<br>
  

</div>
```

Comment: Remove the second `animate`, use `height: 20` in the first.

Comment: lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$('div').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("animate");
});
```

```css
.square {
height:120px;
width: 100px;
background:black;
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;

transition:all 750ms;
}

.animate{
  height:20px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square">

  1<br>
  2<br>
  3<br>
  4<br>
  5<br>
  6<br>
  7<br>
  8<br>
  9<br>
  

</div>
```